# How work QMenu close mechanism?

Tags: qt, events, menu

I have QMenu with 3 layers and I am confused why QMenu didn't closed if I setChecked one of 2-nd layer menus? If I click on 3-rd layer menu, it dissapear. How work hiding mechanism of QMenu? How can I hide first layer menu from 2-nd layer by send some signal and not close first layer menu manually by QWidget::close() function?